# Regarding the message of ignoring visible gpu devices

Tags: tensorflow, gpu

When running a tensorflow program leveraging GPU devices, I got the following message. What does the statement of `Ignoring visible gpu 
   device (device: 0, name: Quadro 5000, pci bus id: 0000:05:00.0) with Cuda 
   compute capability 2.0.` mean? What is to be ignored?

```
2017-12-04 16:06:17.784599: I 
tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:887] Found device 0 with 
properties:
name: Quadro 5000
major: 2 minor: 0 memoryClockRate (GHz) 1.026
pciBusID 0000:05:00.0
Total memory: 2.50GiB
Free memory: 2.22GiB
2017-12-04 16:06:17.784636: I 
tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:908] DMA: 0
2017-12-04 16:06:17.784645: I 
tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:918] 0:   Y
2017-12-04 16:06:17.784658: I 
tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:950] Ignoring visible gpu 
device (device: 0, name: Quadro 5000, pci bus id: 0000:05:00.0) with Cuda 
compute capability 2.0. The minimum required Cuda capability is 3.0.
```

Answer (score 2):

TensorFlow prints this message when you have a GPU installed in the local machine but its [compute capability](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-faq) is too low for TensorFlow to use that GPU for accelerated computation. As the error message states:

> The minimum required Cuda capability is 3.0.

This means that you must use a CUDA-capable GPU with compute capability 3.0 or greater to use TensorFlow for GPU.